# Is it possible or not to share a geometry among many meshes and applied a different shaderMaterial for each?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I instanciate one PlaneGeometry, then I instanciate 200 meshes sharing this geometry and with their own instance of a given shaderMaterial. Here is a simplified version of the code :

```
...
var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10,2,2);
var meshes = [];
var material=null;

for (var i=0 ; i<200 ; i++)
{
   var elevations = getElevations(i); //return an array of 9 values, values are different for each mesh
   var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
               vertexShader : vsAlti, //process displacement on y coordinate of the vertex
               fragmentShader : fsAlti,
               attributes : { elevation :  { type : 'f',value : elevations }}
            };
   meshes.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometry , mat));
}
...
```

Although, the array value of the elevation attributes is different for each mesh, only one is applied for all of them. It looks like only one instance of shaderMaterial is applied to all the meshes. I would rather expect that for each mesh the shader with the matching attribute elevation values would be applied.

**Edit :**

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/McNulty/L584j/119/

Answer (score 0):

try this code.. and let me know, how it work..

```
var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10,2,2);
var meshes = [];
var material=null;
var attrib = {
     elevations: {
        type: 'f',
        value: []
     }};
for (var i=0 ; i<20 ; i++){

    attrib.elevations.value[i] = (10*i) + 0.25 ; // for example
}
var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ vertexShader : vsAlti, 
           fragmentShader : fsAlti,
           attributes : attrib });
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry , mat);
scene.add(mesh)
```

Comment: The code above doesn't really help. It's giving 20 values to the elevations attribute, whereas the PlaneGeometry is made of 9 vertices. Actually, the shader works as expected, if I create one geometry for each meshes, it works. The problem is when I share a geometry among several meshes. They all look the same.

Comment: can you share your code or link in jsfiddle... it might help to round your problem..

Comment: I've edited the question with a link to the jsfiddle snippet.

Comment: `var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.clone() , mat);
scene.add(mesh)`.. It will do the trick.. let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Doing that will duplicate the geometry and the idea is to share one instance of geometry among many meshes. Like I said before, if I use one instance of geometry per mesh, it works.

Comment: without cloning the geometry, i think it's not possible, one geometry can be shared to many meshes, that's right, you can share it, but here you have to note the geometry vertices,(i.e) it have been shared(not cloned) to create mesh, so on each an every mesh creation the changes will append in all the mesh you created.. so without cloning the geometry it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to share geometry and have different material for each mesh at the same time. Your code seems to be correct in this. Are you sure your shaders react properly on different elevation values?

When you create two meshes with two different geometries and two different shader materials, then it works?

Comment: Yes the shaders react properly. If I use a different geometry for each meshe, then it works.

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable about shaders, so I am only guessing here. I think that normally shaders only affect how things look like and don't affect any values in your object graph, but it is possible that your shaders actually change vertices in geometry object itself and as it is shared between all meshes, then all of them change shape in the same way. Hopefully somebody with insight into shaders will look on your shader code and explain this to us.